# How to swap file path and queries from Java code

Tags: java, path

I have a "how-should-I-implement- it- on -the-  best- way -in -java" question. I have written a program in Java that reads a csv file that is stored on a fixed directory. (BufferedReader & FileReader) The file is then read out and the data is displayed in an XYDataset (XY graph) using jFreeChart.

Question: The program should now run without a development interface, that means I export it as .exe. However, since the directory is now to be "independent", that means it  can be changed at any time, I should now save the directory externally and / or stored it should be without the code must be changed. In addition, the data from the directory (csv-files) should also be called regardless of the code. That means there are different .csv files inside the directory & you should sort by name & most recent date. That It should always open the latest .csv file with the "1" in the name and another time the .csv file with the "2" in the name. My question is now: How should I implement this best?
My first idea would be an XML file to access my Java program, but I do not know exactly how I should store the file path there.
maybe like this: ? file: /// H: /Test/Testfile.csv

Does somebody know how to "outsourced"  & then accessed a directory or other ideas, how I could implement that outside the "real" code?
Would be very happy about help!

Comment: I _guess_ easiest way would be to ask for path(user input) before execution. If it's console app, read input with `Scanner`, check whether it's a valid CSV path, go ahead and perform your task.

Comment: I appreciate that works very well, but then I need 4 different versions of the .exe. Because I would like to search the directory outside of code.  Each .exe is to sort in each case according to a number & then read out. In java-code does it work very easy, but can not I you also outsource the queries? Maybe is it possible with another format?